# How to redirect example.com to www.example.com with DNS and IIS?

Tags: seo, asp.net, duplicate-content, iis7, no-www

How can I redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com` using DNS / IIS?  I wish to do this for an asp.net web site to prevent duplicate contents (Bad for SEO).

I had 2 a record in dns (Windows Server 2008) for `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

Also in IIS I added `example.com` and `www.example.com` in edit bindings.

Which changes should I do in my IIS and DNS to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`?

Should I change the `web.config` file in my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to set up another site for the one you want to redirect in IIS. You then configure that site to be a redirection to the other one.

See here for details on setting up the redirect http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(WS.10).aspx

to install http redirection

1. Click Start, click All Programs, Click Administrative Tools, Click
   Server Manager
2. Expand Roles in the left bar, and click Web Server (IIS)
3. In the main window, click Add Role Services
4. In the Common HTTP Features, check HTTP Redirect and then click
   Install

both DNS entries need to point at your server, so that clients know how to get to either one. Remove the binding for example.com from your original site. Add a new site bound to example.com, and make this redirect to www.example.com

Comment: really thanks for answer / Http Redirection role not always installed in IIS 7.0 -> how can i install it ? / also which part of my iis or dns should i remove or change?

Answer (score 2):

In IIS, you can **add a second host header** in the **Bindings section** of a web application, so the same web application can answer `example.com` and `www.example.com`. This assumes that you don't care which URL is displayed in the browser address bar. A single entry in the DNS table for `example.com` should suffice in this case.

In this case HTTPS binding for both domain names can not be applied.